# CoreData issue SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui, unrecognized-selector

I am new in Swift and am working on a project using core data. I created my entity (called StudentData) comprehensive of all the attributes that I am using in my coding. I have a view with a list of clients and when you tap on each of them a view with some attributes will show, here is the code:

```
struct StudentView: View {
    @Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    @State var selectedStudent = StudentData()
    let myStudent: StudentData
    
var body: some View {
            HStack {
                        Text("Subject")
                            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                         Spacer()
                       Text("\(myStudent.subject ?? "No Subject")")
                        .font(.title2)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                
            }
               HStack {
                Text("School Year")
                        .font(.system(size: 30, weight:.bold, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                    
                        Spacer()
                Text("Year \(myStudent.schoolYear ?? "Unknown")")
                    .font(.title2)
                    .bold()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
 }
            HStack {
               Text("Address")
                        .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .italic()
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        Spacer()
                        Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                            showingSheet = true
                        }) {
                            Text(("\(myStudent.address ?? "Unknown")")).underline()
                        }
 }.navigationBarTitle(myStudent.name ?? "No Name")
         .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(myStudent:selectedStudent)) {
                                Text("More Details")
```

Moving to the DetailView the code is:

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(entity: StudentData.entity(), sortDescriptors: [],
animation: .spring()) var chapter: FetchedResults<StudentData>
@Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
@State var showModalView = false
let myStudent: StudentData
@State var selectedStudent = StudentData()
var body: some View {
VStack{
                        Text("Topics Covered")
                            .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                    Text("\(myStudent.chapter ?? "-")")
                     .font(.title2)
                     .bold()
                     .foregroundColor(.white)
                     .padding(.horizontal)
                    }
  }.sheet(isPresented: $showModalView, content: {
            TopicView(topic: selectedStudent)})
```

However when I tap on the button to show the detail view the app crashes and this error shows:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[StudentData chapter]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000157b380'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.
So I understand the error is clearly related to the attribute 'chapter' in my entity but I don't really figure out what I am doing wrong.
Thanks for anyone who'll help.

Comment: How do you select the student? If `StudentData`is a `NSManagedObject`subclass actually you cannot create an instance with  the default initializer `StudentData()` because there is not connection to the managed object context.

Comment: This is how I select the student from my list view: ForEach(items id: \.self) { (retrievedStudent: StudentData) and .onTapGesture {
                                selectedStudent = retrievedStudent

Comment: `@State var selectedStudent = StudentData()`, remove all occurrences of this line from your code. It makes no sense and you should have only one property of type StudentData in both the StudentView and the DetailView

Comment: Sorry I know the question sounds stupid but what is the logic for the argument when I call the DetailView from my studentview?

Comment: I see that you have a fetch request variable chapter in your detail view, not only does it looks unnecessary but is this what you are trying to access when you call myStudent.chapter? Not sure I understand your last question but I believe you want to call the DetailView with the same object that was passed to StudentView

Comment: Yes that fetch request is meant to fetch the attribute 'chapter' from my entity. The student view was called using the var selectedStudent but if I remove it from my detail and student view as you suggested then I am not sure what instance to use

Comment: Since it gives me this error: 'Missing argument for parameter 'myStudent' in call'

Comment: Ok if StudentView was called with a value for selectedStudent then you only need to remove the initializer so you don’t create a new object as well. Instead remove myStudent, there is no need to have two student properties, right?  You never need a fetch request to access a property if you already have the object (selectedStudent). And in DetailView I think selectedStudent should be declared using @Binding.

Comment: I need myStudent in StudentView to call the different attributes. I removed the fetch request but the crash keeps happening with the same error.